# How to get ads to refresh using googletag.pubads().refresh()?

Tags: google-dfp

I have an ad and a link in a page like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
<title>DPT - Asynchronous + Single Rest Architecture</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    (function() {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
    })();
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
    googletag.defineSlot('/1001256/Home_Top_Leaderboard_728x90', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72" style="width:728px; height:90px;">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72'); });
      </script>
    </div>
    <a id="refresh" href="#">Refresh ad</a>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function ($) {
        $('#refresh').click(function() {
         googletag.cmd.push(googletag.pubads().refresh());
        return false;
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first time I click the link, the ad refreshes. All other times nothing happens. Even just calling the refresh() method in Firebug etc does nothing after the first time.

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: Any luck getting refresh() to work? I'm having the same issue still.

Comment: Are you using any url rewrite method ????

Answer (score 4):

According to https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089 the refresh function takes a parameter of an array of adSlots:

`googletag.pubads().refresh([gptAdSlots[0], gptAdSlots[1]]);`

Does that change the behaviour for you?

Failing that, I would recommend enabling the Google Publisher Console by adding the `google_console` or `googfc` parameter to your querystring (see https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/181070?hl=en for details), and checking for errors

Answer (score 4):

This is the source of the problem

`googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();`

Stop using singlerequest mode and you can call googletag.pubads().refresh() with no problem. Not managed to find any documentation explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
googletag.pubads().refresh(null, {changeCorrelator: false});
```

From https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference:

> Fetches and displays new ads for specific or all slots on the page. Works only in asynchronous rendering mode. 
>   For proper behavior across all browsers, calling refresh must be preceded by a call to display the ad slot. If the call to display is omitted, refresh may behave unexpectedly. If desired, the disableInitialLoad method can be used to stop display from fetching an ad.

and:

> Configuration options associated with this refresh call. changeCorrelator specifies whether or not a new correlator is to be generated for fetching ads. Our ad servers maintain this correlator value briefly (currently for 30 seconds, but subject to change), such that requests with the same correlator received close together will be considered a single page view. By default a new correlator is generated for every refresh.

I hope it helped a little at least.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any answer to the issue right now. I encountered the same problem in the site I am currently working and lucky enough to accidentally solve the issue by adding $(window).load(function(){ }); in the javascript code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This just signifies that the page needs to be completely loaded before executing googletag command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define slot in both the parts:

```
<script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/xxxx/suihgdwiuhdwiu', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-    ad-xxxxxxx-0').
    setTargeting("test", "refresh").
    addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
      });
    </script>
```

And:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxx-0' class="adsbygoogle">
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxx-0'); });
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);}, 60000);
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have got your ad unit definition quite right.

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DFP test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
        (function() {
        var gads = document.createElement('script');
        gads.async = true;
        gads.type = 'text/javascript';
         var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
        })();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
        googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/Home_Top_Leaderboard_728x90', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72' style='width:728px; height:90px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72'); });
        </script>
    </div>

    <a id="refresh" href="#">Refresh ad</a>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function ($) {
            $('#refresh').click(function() {
                googletag.cmd.push(googletag.pubads().refresh());
                return false;
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously to get this working you will need to change /1234567/Home_Top_Leaderboard_728x90 to the correct values.

Comment: Tried that, too. I have another page using the Single Rest Architecture code almost identical to yours and the same thing happens.  Ads only refresh once on first click. I'm using inline ad calls as the docs hint that you can't use the refresh method with SRA.

Comment: Ok now that I have looked at your full code, there is not anything wrong with it as far as I can see... I tried replacing the ad unit you called with one of my ones and it worked perfectly (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/122349/original.html). So what I think is happening is that you only have one line item targeted at that ad unit at the moment? Try adding another line item or another creative to the same line item... as far as I can see (using the chrome network tab) there is a call being done each time to refresh the ad but as there is nothing new to show it is just not being updated...

Comment: Any luck getting refresh() to work?  I'm having the same issue still.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:
googletag.pubads().updateCorrelator();
googletag.pubads().refresh();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the ad slot are refresh perhaps may using this method,

```js
<!-- header script -->
<script async='true' src='https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    var REFRESH_KEY='refresh';
    var REFRESH_VALUE='true';
</script>
<script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        var slot_bottomframe = googletag.defineSlot('/1001256/Home_Top_Leaderboard_728x90', [728,90], 'div-gpt-ad-1342320102476-72');
        slot_leaderboard.setTargeting('pos',['leaderboard']);
        slot_leaderboard.setTargeting(REFRESH_KEY,REFRESH_VALUE);
        slot_leaderboard.addService(googletag.pubads());
            
        var SECOND = 60;
        googletag.pubads().addEventListener('impressionViewable',function(event) {
            var slot=event.slot;
            if(slot.getTargeting(REFRESH_KEY).indexOf(REFRESH_VALUE)>-1) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
              }, SECOND*1000);
            }
        });

        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
        googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```